# Incorrect date format conversion with TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, textbox

I want `MM/dd/yyyy` date format but TextBox gives this date format `yyyy-MM-dd`. While TextMode is Date.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtChkEventDate" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I've used this code to convert the format:

```
string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy" };
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtChkEventDate.Text, formats, 
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

But it show error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How I can convert `yyyy-MM-dd` into `MM/dd/yyyy` date format?

Comment: `string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy" };` should just be  a `string` you need to brush up on the basics in C# .net in regards to `string[] vs string` datatype

Comment: What is the exact value of `txtChkEventDate.Text`?

Comment: also read up on the `.ToString()` overload and `string.Format()` method

Comment: value is 2017-12-14

Comment: @Asif.Ali: You're trying to parse it with the format string `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.  `ParseExact` literally means *exact*.  You're using the wrong format string.

Comment: @MethodMan that's not working with `string formats = "MM/dd/yyyy";`.

Comment: it works , you just don't know how to use it correctly that's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment on the question:

> value is 2017-12-14

That input doesn't match the format string you're using: `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

You have to use a format string which matches your source format:  `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

For example:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtChkEventDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

When parsing a value *from* a string, the format string you use is what matches the *incoming* data string.  If you want to *output* the parsed value in a different format at a later time, *that's* when you'd use a different format string to specify that output.  For example:

```
someLabel.Text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formats variable is supposed to be an array of allowed formats. The date format you pass into ParseExact is not in your formats variable, so it throws an error. Relevant passage from documentation:

> The formats parameter contains an array of patterns, one of which s must match exactly if the parse operation is to succeed. The patterns in the formats parameter consists of one or more custom format specifiers from the Custom Date and Time Format Strings table, or a single standard format specifier, which identifies a predefined pattern, from the Standard Date and Time Format Strings table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx